# The connection does not have any active transactions

Tags: c#, dbcontext, .net-7.0

I just installed .NET 7 SDK and updated csproj from     `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` to     `<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>` and updated corresponding NuGet packages from MS.

From that moment on, I get an exception when calling `await BeginTransaction()` from code below:

> The connection does not have any active transactions.

```
public class DBservice<TDB> where TDB : DbContext
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
   private readonly DbContext _db;
   private readonly DbConnection _connection;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

   private IDbContextTransaction _transaction { get; set; }
   
   public DBservice(IServiceProvider services, IHttpContextAccessor context)
   {
      _services = services;
      _db = services.GetRequiredService<TDB>();
      _connection = _db.Database.GetDbConnection();
      _context = context;
   }

   public async Task BeginTransaction()
   {
      if (_transaction is not null) { return; }
      _transaction = await 
      _db.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
   }
}
```

This code worked perfectly with .NET 6. Is there any new way how to create a transaction in .NET 7? Or why is this code no longer working?

Comment: I fixed a similar issue on my side by upgrading Visual Studio to version 17.4

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

When not using await BeginTransaction() another exception was shown

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process.

I had to add `TrustServerCertificate=True` or `Encrypt=False` to my MS SQL server connection string.